# Is "short" extraneous and ungrammatical in "short abbreviation"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[Abbreviation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abbreviation): Meaning *"a short form of a word or phrase"*

See for example the following original sentence;

> We generally use the [abbreviation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abbreviation) 'MP' instead of writing out 'Member
>   of Parliament' in full.

What if someone says "short abbreviation" in the above sentence, would it be extraneous and ungrammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly correct grammar.  It may be redundant in some situations, but not always.

> The village of Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch is usually abbreviated to Llanfairpwllgwyngyll, or to the short abbreviation Llanfair PG.

It can also be used to indicate that an abbreviation is considered short (by the standard of abbreviations)

> MP, BBC and c. (for circa) are all short abbreviations, unlike the text slang "IITYWIMWYBMAD" which means "if I tell you what it means, will you buy me a drink"

So it is grammatical. It may be redundant. The redundancy may be on purpose, to contrast or emphasise a point. In this case, it is saying MP is an abbreviation for Member of Parliament, and this abbreviation is particularly short.

Comment: What an amazing village name, man! "Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch" is 58 seemingly random letters. ^^

Answer (score -1):

"Short Abbreviation" is redundant, and of no value, unless two abbreviations are being compared, and one is short compared to the other. "Short Abbreviation" is not ungrammatical, but it is not natural and should be avoided unless in a particular context it actually adds to the meaning.

While "short Abbreviation" can be meaningful and useful in specific contexts, in most cases, including the sense suggested by the question, it should be avoided as redundant.